# How to get dataset formatted properly in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

So far I have been able to get it so that the user can upload data into shiny app (dynamic upload). How can I get it so that the uploaded dataframe is nicely formatted (see link below). I believe the library I want to use is DT but I am open to other options. The code is below

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

[This is what I want the dataset that is uploaded to appear like for the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIIP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `renderDataTable` and `dataTableOutput`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  }, options = list(pageLength = 5))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also you may try `DT` package which has functions with same name. Use it with `DT::renderDataTable` and `DT::dataTableOutput`.

Comment: right now its hard to see certain datasets because the table is so big, is there a way to limit the table size? Thank you!

Comment: You can set  `pageLength = 5` to show only 5 rows in a page. Change 5 to any value you want. @jasmine